# Ruby On Rails - Extend Module in controller

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, module

I have Module log_exception in lib folder as follows:

/lib/log_exception.rb

```
module LogException
  def Log(e, message="")
    Rails.logger.error "#{message}: #{e.message}"
    e.backtrace[0..13].each {|line| Rails.logger.error line}
  end
end

extend LogException
```

And now I am trying to use the Log method (which will be class method as module is extended) directly in this controller as:

```
Log(e, "Error in home action of DashboardController")
```

But it is giving me the following error:

```
undefined method `Log' for #<DashboardController
```

I have also set following in my application.rb

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

If I extend same module in any of Model(User) and call the same method as

```
User.Log(e, "Error in home action of DashboardController")
```

then it is working fine, but not in case of controller.

I have tried various options but no luck.

Could anyone explains me what I am doing wrong? or How can I extend Module in controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `include`, not `extend`.

What `extend` gives you is possibility to do

```
ControllerName.Log(...)
```

But what you really want, is to be able to use the method on the controller instances (since while being in the `home` action you are actually operating on the ***controller instance***), not on controller itself.

## Edit:

> One more thing Can I access same method directly without doing include
>   or extend on module? if yes can you please share?

```
module LogException
  def Log(e, message="")
    Rails.logger.error "#{message}: #{e.message}"
    e.backtrace[0..13].each {|line| Rails.logger.error line}
  end
  extend self
end

LogException.Log(your_error, your_message)
```

Comment: @Tushar no probs, make sure to accept the answer since it solved the issue.

Comment: Accepted you answer, One more thing Can I access same method directly without doing include or extend on module? if yes can you please share?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Which one should be preferred ? to include/extend or accessing directly ?

Comment: @Tushar It is a matter of taste and your approach to design really. I don't think that having it in the latter form is a bad idea in your case. I would recommend you to go through the [Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) and [Rails Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide) to have a grasp about community accepted conventions (you will get tons of use from it)

Comment: OK Thanks for your help.